# How to create an alert in Prometheus with time units? Like "average response time surpasses 5 seconds in the last 2 minutes"

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

```yaml
  - name: app
    rules:
      - alert: ServerHighLatency
        expr: sum by(applicationName) (rate(http_server_requests_seconds_sum{status!~"4..|5.."}[1m]))/sum by(applicationName) (rate(http_server_requests_seconds_count{status!~"4..|5.."}[1m])) >= 5s
        for: 5s
        labels:
          severity: critical
        annotations:
          summary: "{{ $labels.applicationName }} is responding with high latency(5s+)"
          description: "*Host*: {{ $labels.node }}\n*Datacenter*: {{ $labels.datacenter }}\n*Value*: {{ humanize $value }}\n"
```

But I got parsing error around the final `s` in the expression, so I guess it is not allowed. When I remove `s` it works, but is never triggered. I cannot find any examples of alerts to examine the average response time within a range, but only comparison by value, like "some percentile > 0.8", but not with time units. Does it make sense?

Side note: I cannot get `{{ $labels.datacenter }}` and `{{ $labels.node }}` working, but `{{ $labels.applicationName }}` is working, why? Where can I find some good examples and documentations of alerts syntax in Prometheus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need (you can't acctually) to add the unit to the expression, just the number. If your alert is never triggered maybe is something wrong with the expression or maybe the result is always less than 5. Have you tested the expression in the Prometheus console?

Comment: Sorry that yesterday I was on another issue. Today I can have a look and check the exp in console. Thanks

Comment: You are right; I see that the time unit is normally included in the metrics name. For me, it is `seconds`. I lower the threshold to `0.001` and it works at last.

Comment: And about the labels not showing, at last I tried with Prometheus expression console and found that only with `sum by(tag1, tag2, tag3)` I can see the labels in the final result, and thus, using them in the `annotations` part; the values are picked at last.

Answer (score 0):

Just a side note about "labels not showing":

If we use Prometheus expression console (under `/graph`), we would see all the labels included in the results, for a quick debugging.

If I `sum(rate(foo([1m]))/sum(rate(bar([1m]))`, I will see this:

[image]

But if I use `sum by(tag1, tag2, tag3)`, I can see the tags in the result:

[image]

And then, the values of tags are no more empty in the final `annotation` part:

```yaml
    rules:
      - alert: HighLatency
        expr: sum by(productName,instance,datacenter) (rate(http_server_requests_seconds_sum{status!~"4..|5.."}[1m]))/sum by(productName,instance,datacenter) (rate(http_server_requests_seconds_count{status!~"4..|5.."}[1m])) >= 5
        for: 5s
        labels:
          severity: critical
        annotations:
          summary: "{{ $labels.productName }} is responding with high latency(5s+)"
          description: "*Instance*: {{ $labels.instance }}\n*Datacenter*: {{ $labels.datacenter }}\n*Value*: {{ humanize $value }}\n"
```

I can see them in Slack channel.